# Tried databse queryset on crontab but it doesn't work

Tags: python, django, cron

Crontab works fine on simple task.
e.g

```
def test():
    test.objects.create.(name='Dino')

#It also works on this
def test_task()
    if Users_Machine.objects.filter().exists():
        test.objects.create(name='Dino')
```

but when i tried to query my db with foreignkey it does nothing.

Have tried this two methods:

```
#request method
def test_task(request):
    if Users_Machine.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
        test.objects.create(name='Dino', user=request.user)

#direct methods
def test_task()
    if Users_Machine.objects.filter().exists():
        name=Users_Machine.objects.get()
        test.objects.create(name='Dino', user=name.username)
```

The Users_Machine.object returns True

Here is my models

```
#users_machine model
class Users_Machine(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

#test model
class test(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Please how can i make this work?

Comment: `if Users_Machine.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists()` does this return true?

Comment: Yes my Users_Machine object returns true @SourabhBurse
And the timing is set to 1 minute just to confirm if its working but it doesn't

Comment: I think you need to get pk from User_machine and then use it to create test.object

Comment: Use `id=  User_machine.objects.get(_foo_=request.user)` to get primary key of User and then pass it like this `test.objects.create(name='foo', user=id`.

Comment: Have tried this. It didn’t work either

Comment: Try creating test object without user like this `test.objects.create(name='Dino')`

Comment: Yes it works without the user filed but i wanted the object to create base on user that exists in User_Machine object

Comment: Can you post `User_Machine` model?
And please post how you tried to get the `object` of `User_Machine`.

Comment: Ok. please scroll up and check, have updated the model and the methods I tried to solve it but yet I can't still get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if I get to look at `User` model but for now I am going to assume in the request, you are passing `Name` field which is present in the `UserMachine` model and you can create new object in `test` model as follows:

```
def test_task(request):
    Current_user = User_Machine.objects.get(Name = request.name)  
    if Current_user:
        test.objects.create(name='Dino', user=Current_user)
```

Can you please add `User` model as well, that will allow me fine tune the answer (or correct it if this one is wrong)?

Comment: Am using Django default user model that has a filed firstName, lastname, username, email etc

Comment: In the request am passing in user which is foreignkey. 

A little clarification here, a user send a request that got that Users_machine object created, now I want to use cronjob to do some background adding base on the present user request. Cronjob please check if this object is present in the database. If yes then get the user who created the request and create another object for that user.

Comment: are you sure that the `FK` is being passed to the request correctly? and I am having trouble understanding why you want to use `CRON` if you are getting request from the user in the first place.
`CRON` is more of `async` job which will be executed in the back on specified interval. But if you are getting `request` from the user then why not create object in the same place?

Comment: Am not getting any request from the user, I just want ‘cron’ to create the object for me. That’s why I tried the second method without pasig in ’request’ but it still didn’t work.

Comment: Request method should definitely work unless and until you are doing something wrong, I'd be happy to assist you. Do let me know if you are using Pycharm (so we can connect on codewithme) or any other platform.

Comment: I used vi and vscode on Linux operating system but I don’t mind sharing my code with you if you can help me out cause am beginning to think maybe crontab can’t handle database queries so am trying to study celery but dam celery concept is not easy on newbies like me.

Comment: Alright drop your github repo link

Comment: https://github.com/Dino-Corry/Web_solution

We can communicate privately if you dont mind

Comment: Have seen the problem but not my solution. The problem is because the Users_machines object is more than when that's why cron couldn't create the test object but i want cron to create object base on the number of object available in Users_machine.

I dont know if this logic will be possible. Will it??

Comment: So you are saying that `Objects` in `USER_MACHINES` are more than `TEST` that is why cron is unable to create object in `test`?
- It doesn't matter if `objects` are more or less.


> but i want cron to create object base on the number of object available in Users_machine. I dont know if this logic will be possible. Will it?
- If `Users_machine` has 10 objects then you want to make 10 objects in `test`? is this the case?

It would be helpful if you give example of your expected outcome. I will be cloning your repo and see what could be done.

Comment: This celery tutorial should help : [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THxCy-6EnQM&t=130s)

Comment: If Users_machine has 50 objects then you want to make 50 objects in test? YES this the logic i want and please not this 50 objects is coming from diff users.

Comment: Thanks for the celery video, I'll check it out.